# Getting crash while fetch data from Database in swift

Tags: swift

I have the table view in which i want to display all data from database..here is code...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cuntries") as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier:"cuntries")
    }
    var dbPath: NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    dbPath = dbPath .stringByAppendingPathComponent("UserDetail.sqlite")
    var db = IMDDB()
    var userinfo : UseInfoModel = UseInfoModel()
    db.initWithPath(dbPath);
    var arrayUserData = db.lookupAllForSQL("select * from UserData") as NSArray

    cell?.textLabel.text = arrayUserData[indexPath.row] as NSString //Getting crash
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "hello"
    cell?.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    return cell!
}
```

but it will crash..

Comment: what is the crash log?

Comment: You probably have classic index-out-of-bounds error. Why do you think that number of rows in TableView will be equal to number of rows in database table?

Comment: No log while crash..... from data base, the array is like ..... array(
        {
        "User_Id" = 1;
        "User_Name" = sdfs;
        "User_Password" = sdfdsf;
    },
        {
        "User_Id" = 3;
        "User_Name" = xyz;
        "User_Password" = "1234)";
    }
)

Comment: `arrayUserData[indexPath.row] as NSString` will not work, because as you just showed us, it's not an array of strings. It appears to be an array of dictionaries. So grab that dictionary and then extract the `User_Name` field from that (or whatever). BTW, this is extremely inefficient, retrieving all rows from the table every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

Comment: Then how can I done this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's Array -> Dictonary..So i have to code it like..

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserData") as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier:"UserData")
    }
    var dbPath: NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    dbPath = dbPath .stringByAppendingPathComponent("UserDetail.sqlite")
    var db = IMDDB()
    var userinfo : UseInfoModel = UseInfoModel()
    db.initWithPath(dbPath);
    var arrayUserData = db.lookupAllForSQL("select * from UserData") as NSArray
    var arraydata = arrayUserData[indexPath.row] as NSMutableDictionary
    cell?.textLabel.text = arraydata["User_Name"] as NSString
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = arraydata["User_Password"] as NSString
    cell?.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    return cell!
}
```